# How to shorten unlock time in 22.04

Tags: password, lock-screen, 22.04, unlock

I'v just installed a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 on a Dell latitude 5480. Except for upgrading the packages, I haven't done anything - not even changing the driver (default is xorg).

When the screen is locked, e.g. after sleep or just lock (super+l), I type the correct password, it takes ~6 seconds to unlock.

Played with it a bit and found something strange: If I type a wrong password, I get the same 6 seconds delay (without the unlocking of course), but if I now enter the correct password, the unlock is immediate.

Something is causing the delay for the first time, regardless of the correctness of the password...

Any idea how to make the unlock faster? As I said before, the laptop is updated with the latest packages (sudo apt update + upgrade).

Comment: Same here (fresh 22.04.1 install 6 sec delay on unlock, 0 if after wrong password attempt), dell as well (precision 5520)

Answer (score 2):

It looked like nvidia driver issue.
Mine was nvidia-driver-515 and I had the same issue.
After I changed it to -510, it is quick now.

Please refer this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1441661/224225

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue as you when using wayland windowing system on Latitude 5500. It seems that the graphics card wasn't installed, as it is not yet available for ubuntu 22 (I hope it will be available soon), and from the answers I found seems like this would be the problem with Wayland.

I just switched to xorg windowing system for now (but you loose all the cool trackpad features)

This is the link from where I got the instructions on how to enable xorg. And also be able to switch between them on user login screen:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop

Basically you need to do the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Set te WaylandEnabled variable to true and uncomment the line:

```
WaylandEnable=true
```

Then just restart the service:

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm3
```

After this, on the login screen where you insert your password, you will have the option to select - from the **bottom right corner** - the windowing system you want, so you should select "ubuntu xorg" instead of "ubuntu" which is Wayland.

I hope this will help you with the problem until we eventually get a graphics card driver.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with ubuntu 22.04 nvidia-dirver-530. After taking long time to unlock, running `sudo systemctl status gdm3` produced `FATAL: Module nvidia not found in directory /lib/modules/5.19.0-43-generic/`.Meanwhile,I have  similar symptoms produced accoring to [this answer's trouble shooting](https://askubuntu.com/a/1437164/1702143).

I found that I did not install the `nvidia-dkms` with the `apt policy nvidia-dkms-530` command. But running `apt policy nvidia-driver-530`,`apt policy linux-modules-nvidia-530-5.19.0-43-generic`, I found  that I have installed the both.

After apt installing the corresponding version of dkms for nvidia driver,it enters desktop immediately after inputing the correct password:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-dkms-530
```

Answer (score -1):

Delete and clean up your os from garbage and unnecessary files. You should also check that any startup application which can be heavy to load or you have set more applications to startup as the os loads.

You can use gui apps like spacer. install : `sudo apt install stacer`

Answer (score -1):

I think people are on the Wrong Path here, there is something wrong with Ubuntu since version 20 with the password verification subsystem, I have seen systems work fine, then one day will start taking 10 seconds to even do a sudo, this is NOT a screen issue but anything related to password verification

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).