# Syslog error: "modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-37-generic"

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, 22.04

After regular update (`apt update && apt dist-upgrade`) of my desktop computer to Linux Kernel `5.15.0-37-generic` two days ago, `syslog` started filling with the following error:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-37-generic
```

Any ideas?

More info about my system:

```
# dkms status
fwts-efi-runtime-dkms/22.03.00, 5.15.0-35-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
fwts-efi-runtime-dkms/22.03.00, 5.15.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
virtualbox/6.1.32, 5.15.0-35-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox/6.1.32, 5.15.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed

# uname -rv
5.15.0-37-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 1 19:16:45 UTC 2022

# ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001C8Dsv00001D05sd00001042bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-510-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-510 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

# ll /lib/modules/5.15.0-3[57]-generic/kernel/
/lib/modules/5.15.0-35-generic/kernel/:
total 92
drwxr-xr-x  23 root root 4096 Jun  3 12:32 ./
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root 4096 Jun 11 16:43 ../
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Jun  3 12:32 arch/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun  3 12:32 block/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 4096 Jun  3 12:32 crypto/
drwxr-xr-x 111 root root 4096 Jun  3 12:32 drivers/
drwxr-xr-x  60 root root 4096 Jun  3 12:32 fs/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun  3 12:32 kernel/
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root 4096 Jun  3 12:32 lib/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun  3 12:32 mm/
drwxr-xr-x  61 root root 4096 Jun  3 12:32 net/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Jun  3 12:32 nvidia-390/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Jun  3 12:32 nvidia-418srv/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Jun  3 12:32 nvidia-450srv/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Jun  3 12:32 nvidia-470/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Jun  3 12:32 nvidia-470srv/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Jun 11 16:43 nvidia-510/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Jun  3 12:32 nvidia-510srv/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 4096 Jun  3 12:32 samples/
drwxr-xr-x  16 root root 4096 Jun  3 12:32 sound/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Jun  3 12:32 ubuntu/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun  3 12:32 v4l2loopback/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun  3 12:32 zfs/

/lib/modules/5.15.0-37-generic/kernel/:
total 64
drwxr-xr-x  16 root root 4096 Jun  9 21:16 ./
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root 4096 Jun 11 17:26 ../
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Jun  9 21:16 arch/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun  9 21:16 block/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 4096 Jun  9 21:16 crypto/
drwxr-xr-x 111 root root 4096 Jun  9 21:16 drivers/
drwxr-xr-x  60 root root 4096 Jun  9 21:16 fs/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun  9 21:16 kernel/
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root 4096 Jun  9 21:16 lib/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun  9 21:16 mm/
drwxr-xr-x  61 root root 4096 Jun  9 21:16 net/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 4096 Jun  9 21:16 samples/
drwxr-xr-x  16 root root 4096 Jun  9 21:16 sound/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Jun  9 21:16 ubuntu/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun  9 21:16 v4l2loopback/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun  9 21:16 zfs/

# dpkg --list | grep -E "^ii.*linux-(headers|image|hwe|modules)"
ii  linux-headers-5.15.0-35                           5.15.0-35.36                            all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.15.0
ii  linux-headers-5.15.0-35-generic                   5.15.0-35.36                            amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-5.15.0-37                           5.15.0-37.39                            all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.15.0
ii  linux-headers-5.15.0-37-generic                   5.15.0-37.39                            amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                             5.15.0.37.39                            amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-35-generic                     5.15.0-35.36                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-37-generic                     5.15.0-37.39                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                               5.15.0.37.39                            amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-modules-5.15.0-35-generic                   5.15.0-35.36                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.15.0-37-generic                   5.15.0-37.39                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-35-generic             5.15.0-35.36                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-37-generic             5.15.0-37.39                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

***Update 1:***

I tried to reinstall `nvidia-driver-510 (proprietary, tested)` using Ubuntu's `/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk` tool. After the update:

```
# dkms status
fwts-efi-runtime-dkms/22.03.00, 5.15.0-35-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
fwts-efi-runtime-dkms/22.03.00, 5.15.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
nvidia/510.73.05, 5.15.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox/6.1.32, 5.15.0-35-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox/6.1.32, 5.15.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
```

But `/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk` and `ll /lib/modules/5.15.0-3[57]-generic/kernel/` outputs stay the same.

However, it seems that the error message has gone away.

***Update 2:***

I did `apt remove fwts-efi-runtime-dkms` and now:

```
# dkms status
nvidia/510.73.05, 5.15.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox/6.1.32, 5.15.0-35-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox/6.1.32, 5.15.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: `dkms status` and `uname -r` please.

Comment: it looks like package `fwts-efi-runtime-dkms` is not longer required (fwts-efi-runtime-dkms/22.03.00, 5.15.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)) Did you try to install any nvidia packages?

Comment: `After updating my desktop computer to 5.15.0-37-generic two days ago` - how did you do that? Using anything else than `apt` ?

Comment: @nobody What is the advised action about package `fwts-efi-runtime-dkms`?

Comment: @Hannu It was just normal and regular Ubuntu update. Something like `apt update && apt dist-upgrade`.

Comment: in my opinion you can remove it. but it is only a warning it should not block dkms it selfs.

Comment: Thanks @nobody. I removed it and I am monitoring. I will update my question if anything new happens.

Answer (score 16):

I encountered this issue after a reboot. To help others find this answer, I'll describe my primary symptoms as well:

- `nvidia-settings` would not show any options other than `Application Profiles` and `nvidia-settings Configuration`
- Only 1 of my 2 displays seemed to be detected and functioning
- `nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info` would return `Unable to query GPU information`
- Running `sudo systemctl status display-manager` produced `modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found in directory /lib/modules/5.17.0-1020-oem`
- Running `modprobe nvidia` produced the same message as above as well

These all pointed to faulty or missing driver installations. Here's what I tried that did not work to resolve the issue:

- Using Software & Updates to switch between driver versions (subsequently rebooting)
- Switching to Nouveau drivers, purging nvidia, and reinstalling nvidia with `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
- Installing drivers specifically picked from `ubuntu-drivers devices`
- Downgrading to previous driver versions via any of the above methods
- Downgrading to previous kernel versions I had available

### What finally worked

**Specifically installing the module package** for my last installed version of the Nvidia driver + linux kernel version. My installed nvidia driver version was `510`, and my kernel version according to `uname -r` is `5.17.0-1020-oem`, therefore I ran:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-nvidia-510-5.17.0-1020-oem
```

(At this point I was also warned that I was missing header files, so I also installed `linux-headers-5.17.0-1020-oem` -- I'm not sure how this happened)

After having installed the module above, I added it with `modprobe`:

```
sudo modprobe nvidia
```

My displays refreshed, and presto -- both displays were detected, and I was back in business.

Comment: Can confirm, this worked for me as well. Kinda weird that that package wasn't installed automatically, but here we are.

Comment: Many thanks, this worked for me!

Comment: # modprobe nvidia -vv
modprobe: INFO: custom logging function 0x40a3e0 registered
modprobe: INFO: context 0x1fd1210 released
- its OK?

Comment: How can I know the version of the nvidia driver?

Comment: finally got my system going again, thanks a lot for posting the solution!

Answer (score 2):

My guess:
You have more than one kernel version installed; this is an effect of that.

Check for installed kernel-related packages with:
`$ dpkg --list | grep -E "^ii.*linux-(headers|image|hwe|modules)"`

... and compare to the output of `uname -rv`

Only one kernel version is *required*, a kernel one step older might be good to keep, in practice; if there would be some kind of related problem (i.e. booting).

Comment: I have the same issue, but only one kernel installed.  It's like the driver is being installed to the wrong location.  Some previous upgrade has broken something.

Comment: Suggestion: Purge all nvidia items listed by `$ dpkg --list | grep -E "^ii.*nvidia.*` and start over, reinstall a single driver package (e.g. hit WinKey then begin to type `Additional Drivers` to launch the GUI-ish installer and use it to reinstall)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, but after upgrading to `kernel 5.15.0-46`, which was leading to nvidia-driver not being loaded error. I followed ***Update 1*** from the question, though installing **nvidia-driver-515** instead. It worked flawlessly.

For those who don't know, you can see boot logs with `journalctl -b`, and then grep nvidia may help find the error on the logs, like this:

```
$ journalctl -b | grep nvidia
modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-46-generic
```

I would have posted this as a comment If I could; I hope this may help others searching for the same error with a recent kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I have a custom kernel from [linux-surface](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup), and after failing with all the GUI methods, I was able to get it to work via apt using the latest dkms version for nvidia:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-530 nvidia-dkms-530
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a command they can just run, here you go:

```bash
ubuntu-drivers devices | grep recommended | grep -oP nvidia-driver-[0-9]* | awk '{sub(/driver-/,""); print}' | { read -d '' x; echo "sudo apt install linux-modules-$x-$(uname -r)"; } | bash
```

It does the following:

1. queries the drivers using `ubuntu-drivers`

```bash
➜  ~ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000
modalias : pci:v0000
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : TU106 [GeForce]
driver   : nvidia-driver-525 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-535-server-open - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free
```

2. filters for the recommended driver using `grep`

```bash
driver   : nvidia-driver-535-server-open - distro non-free recommended
```

3. captures the name of the nvidia driver using `grep`

```bash
nvidia-driver-535
```

4. replaces the `-driver` part with an empty string using `awk`

```bash
nvidia-535
```

5. creates the installation command mentioned in [miend's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1437164/892772) (`$x` is `nvidia-535` here).

```bash
{ read -d '' x; echo "sudo apt install linux-modules-$x-$(uname -r)"; }
```

6. pipes the command to `bash`

Comment: Even after running this command I still couldn't get nvidia-535 to work with ubuntu 20. I eventually dist upgraded to ubuntu 22, which solved the issue.