# Desktop takes time to show up after entering password on login screen

Tags: login, 22.04, lightdm, ubuntu-mate

After entering my password at the login screen, a blank screen appears with a mouse cursor which we can move and after ~2 minutes the desktop shows up. This happens not only after booting but also if I logout and try to log back in. However it does not occur after waking up from suspend state. This started happening after I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 few days back.

System Description:

inxi output:

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.15.0-46-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.2.0
    Desktop: MATE 1.26.0 info: mate-panel wm: marco 1.26.0 vt: 7
    dm: LightDM 1.30.0 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 20KN0002AD v: ThinkPad E480
    serial: <superuser required> Chassis: type: 10 serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: LENOVO model: 20KN0002AD v: SDK0J40697 WIN
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI-[Legacy]: LENOVO v: R0PET35W (1.12 )
    date: 01/22/2018
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 42.7 Wh (100.0%) condition: 42.7/45.3 Wh (94.3%)
    volts: 12.3 min: 11.1 model: SMP 01AV446 type: Li-poly serial: <filter>
    status: Full cycles: 364
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: Intel Core i7-8550U bits: 64 type: MT MCP
    smt: enabled arch: Coffee Lake rev: A cache: L1: 256 KiB L2: 1024 KiB
    L3: 8 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 800 min/max: 400/4000 cores: 1: 800 2: 800 3: 800
    4: 800 5: 800 6: 800 7: 800 8: 800 bogomips: 31999
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620 vendor: Lenovo driver: i915 v: kernel
    ports: active: HDMI-A-1 off: eDP-1 empty: DP-1,HDMI-A-2 bus-ID: 00:02.0
    chip-ID: 8086:5917 class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: AMD Lexa PRO [Radeon 540/540X/550/550X / RX 540X/550/550X]
    vendor: Lenovo driver: amdgpu v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 4
    bus-ID: 02:00.0 chip-ID: 1002:699f class-ID: 0380
  Device-3: Acer SunplusIT Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 1-6:5 chip-ID: 5986:2113 class-ID: 0e02
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 compositor: marco v: 1.26.0
    driver: X: loaded: amdgpu,ati,modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915
    display-ID: :0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1366x768 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 361x203mm (14.2x8.0")
    s-diag: 414mm (16.3")
  Monitor-1: HDMI-1 mapped: HDMI-A-1 model: LG (GoldStar) HD
    serial: <filter> res: 1366x768 hz: 60 dpi: 85 size: 410x230mm (16.1x9.1")
    diag: 470mm (18.5") modes: max: 1366x768 min: 720x400
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 22.0.5 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio vendor: Lenovo
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:9d71
    class-ID: 0403
  Device-2: Microsoft LifeChat LX-3000 Headset type: USB
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid bus-ID: 1-1:2 chip-ID: 045e:070f
    class-ID: 0300
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-46-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    vendor: Lenovo driver: r8169 v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1
    port: c000 bus-ID: 03:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8168 class-ID: 0200
  IF: enp3s0 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth driver: iwlwifi
    v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 05:00.0 chip-ID: 8086:3166
    class-ID: 0280
  IF: wlp5s0 state: up mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-1: docker0 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-2: virbr0 state: down mac: <filter>
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.14 TiB used: 251.25 GiB (21.5%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Kingston model: SA2000M8 250G size: 238.47 GiB
    speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 type: SSD serial: <filter> rev: T1103F0L
    temp: 54.9 C scheme: MBR
  ID-2: /dev/sda vendor: Seagate model: ST1000LM035-1RK172 size: 931.51 GiB
    speed: 6.0 Gb/s type: HDD rpm: 5400 serial: <filter> rev: LCM2 scheme: MBR
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 33.75 GiB used: 13.81 GiB (40.9%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p3
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 3.56 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p6
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 57.0 C pch: 45.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: amdgpu
    temp: 44.0 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 13312 fan-1:
Info:
  Processes: 277 Uptime: 3h 42m wakeups: 9 Memory: 7.44 GiB
  used: 1.75 GiB (23.5%) Init: systemd v: 249 runlevel: 5 Compilers:
  gcc: 11.2.0 alt: 11/7/9 Packages: 2926 apt: 2917 snap: 9 Shell: Bash
  v: 5.1.16 running-in: mate-terminal inxi: 3.3.13
```

Syslog Output covering time (line 274-286)

[image: syslog]

[image]

JournalCtl output covering time (line 149-160. The output is reversed.)

[image: Journctl output]

[image]

Those PCIe logs are related to WiFi/Bluetooth. Ive tried logging in after disabling both but time remains the same. 108 UID belongs to lightdm. I was already using lightdm before upgrade.

Things I've tried but it didn't work:

1. Disabling networking
2. Using xfce instead of lightdm
3. Reinstall MATE DE
4. Creating another user account
5. Disabling VFS daemon
6. Disabling Wifi/Bluetooth
7. Opened a thread at [ubuntuforums.org](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2478238)

Can someone suggest a possible cause for this?

Comment: Your syslog repeatedly shouts about PCI errors. And you seem to have a mysterious user '108' that starts a whole stack, then stops it. Those both suck up a lot of time. Start investigating those.

Comment: Add that information to your Question above. Comments are not intended for conversation. Comments are intended to help you improve your Question until it is answerable.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1409748/13330

Answer (score 4):

As @user1641501 mentioned, it looked like nvidia driver issue.

Mine was `nvidia-driver-515` and I had the same issue which was a quite long unlock time.

After I changed it to `-510` like this:

[image: nvidia driver]

Then the password checking is quick.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04. Fixed the problem by manually installing nvidia-driver-510. It was previously using the recommended nvidia-driver-470.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-510
```